# How to process DELETE having form-encoded body in webapi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, datatables

The client is using DataTables to implement a UI. I am building a C# WebApi backend (full .NET framework suitable for IIS/Azure). For the most part, things line up - mostly json requests, except for one case. The front end wants to delete a batch of records, and formulates the request as an HTTP DELETE with a application/x-www-form-urlencoded body containing the information identifying the records to be deleted. WebApi is supposed to be able to handle form encoding, but in this case, there doesn't seem to be any body available to the ApiController method. FWIW, a sample of the raw request body looks like this:

> action=remove&data%5B4%5D%5BID%5D=4&data%5B4%5D%5BCDID%5D=1&data%5B4%5D%5BTitle%5D=White+Wolf&data%5B4%5D%5BLengthSeconds%5D=215&data%5B5%5D%5BID%5D=5&data%5B5%5D%5BCDID%5D=1&data%5B5%5D%5BTitle%5D=Calm+Lake&data%5B5%5D%5BLengthSeconds%5D=296&data%5B6%5D%5BID%5D=6&data%5B6%5D%5BCDID%5D=1&data%5B6%5D%5BTitle%5D=Blue+Sky&data%5B6%5D%5BLengthSeconds%5D=307

... which URL decoded and prettied up looks like this:

> action:remove
>
> data[4][ID]:4
>
> data[4][CDID]:1
>
> data[4][Title]:White Wolf
>
> data[4][LengthSeconds]:215
>
> data[5][ID]:5
>
> data[5][CDID]:1
>
> data[5][Title]:Calm Lake
>
> data[5][LengthSeconds]:296
>
> data[6][ID]:6
>
> data[6][CDID]:1
>
> data[6][Title]:Blue Sky
>
> data[6][LengthSeconds]:307

I have tried various method signatures to try to get at the content, such as:

```
    public void Delete([FromBody] Dictionary<string,object> myData)
    public void Delete([FromBody] Dictionary<string,string> myData)
    public void Delete([FromBody] string[] myData)
    public void Delete([FromBody] FormUrlEncodedContent myData)
```

but `myData` is always null or empty, and `await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` produces an empty string.

Ideally, I'd like to get the body deserialized to an array of objects, each representing an item to be deleted (3 items as in the example above).

Is this an issue with my code (how do I fix it)?

Is this an issue (limitation) with WebApi framework?

Is this an issue with DataTables (a bug)?

Is this an issue with the way DataTables is used on the client side (what must be done to correct it)?

Comment: That is not a DELETE but looks like a get. You sure its a DELETE?

Comment: Are you using asp.net core? You can use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormCollection` as the model in your `DELETE` controller method. There is also a form collection type if you are not using core but I don't know offhand exactly what it is.

Comment: @CodingYoshi No question. Network traffic captured from the client clearly showed it as an HTTP DELETE with a body as explained. It struck me as unusual, which is why I am wondering if the client is doing the correct thing or if WebApi perhaps doesn't support it.

Comment: Use this in your action: `string[] data`

Comment: @CodingYoshi thanks for the suggestion, now tried without success.

Comment: Did you call it `data` or `myData`? You need to call it `data`. I also think the client is using delete but not sending the data in the body but in the qureystring.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Thanks for the suggestion. Found by testing that parameter name is irrelevant when using [FromBody] (matters when [FromUri]), but network traffic capture clearly shows that it is form data in the request body, not querystring.

Comment: In Web API it is called `FormDataCollection `

Comment: @Crowcoder `FormDataCollection` works i.e. `public void Delete([FromBody] FormDataCollection myData)`. Annoyingly, I get keys containing subscript syntax, basically what I showed in the "cleaned up content" above, but I can work with it. Feel free to post as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
public void Delete([FromBody] FormDataCollection myData)
```

Note that:

`FormDataCollection` is a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`, so for the given example, keys will be "action", "data[4][ID]", "data[4][CDID]", etc.

Since the "[ID]" values are the only items of interest (only need to identify the items to be deleted, the rest can be ignored), the following can be done to extract them into an enumerable:

```
var ids = fields.Where(s => s.Key.Contains("[ID]")).Select(s => int.Parse(s.Value));
```